# BI Publisher - a column's value appearing as a separate row

Tags: oracle-apex, rtf, bi-publisher, oracle-bi

[value at wrong position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blwpX.png)

This value should be above 4 in the next row as upper deviation but somehow it is appearing a separate row.

[actual representation of word rtf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCLrz.png)

This is the actual representation how I want to get rendered in pdf.
Also, the whole thing works fine for some reports but its behaviour changes when there are more than 2 pages of reports.

**Original Scenario**: There can be multiple reports like this which are rendered through for-each loop, this issue occurs when there more than 6 or 7 reports which are having more than 4 number of rows each. I know its very unusual and weird situation but any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stay away from merged or split cells. Use nested tables instead. You can manage margins to make it look like it's the same table.